# GCP BIGQUERY ARIMA_PLUS Model for Multiple Products

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, arima

I am using a BQ MODEL - ARIMA_PLUS for forecasting demand for **multiple products** to predict demand for future 18 months.
The Model is producing results but for one product it is just repeating the forecast with the same number for 18 periods.

I noticed I cannot control/input p,d,q, if I am using multiple products (TIME_SERIES_ID_COL ='Product' )

Any help to fix this issue?

[image: Predictions]

```
 CREATE or REPLACE MODEL ML_Model.Forecast_IL_OB_MONTHLY_ARIMA_OCT20
OPTIONS(
  MODEL_TYPE='ARIMA_PLUS',
  AUTO_ARIMA = TRUE,
  #NON_SEASONAL_ORDER = [1,2,1],
  TIME_SERIES_TIMESTAMP_COL='CalendarMonth',
  TIME_SERIES_DATA_COL = 'Demand',
  TIME_SERIES_ID_COL ='Product',
  HOLIDAY_REGION ='AU',
  CLEAN_SPIKES_AND_DIPS = TRUE,
  DATA_FREQUENCY='MONTHLY'
  #FORECAST_LIMIT_LOWER_BOUND = 0
  #SEASONALITIES = 'YEARLY'

) AS
SELECT CalendarMonth,Revenue,Product FROM `GF.ML_Model.DATA_IL_OB` ;
```

Comment: How do you query your model?

Comment: Not sure but guessing this is what you mean @guillaumeblaquiere
```SELECT * FROM ML.FORECAST(MODEL `GF-.ML_Model.Forecast_IN_OB_MONTHLY_ARIMA`,

                      STRUCT(18 AS horizon, 0.90 AS confidence_level)); ```

Comment: Hmm, the issue should come from the input. Something should be wrong. I don't know what. Are you sure about the column value and name? Your data_col is Demand, but in your query you have Revenue. Is it the issue?

Comment: Ohh, I have just pasted a sample, my code works fine as 9 out of 10 products are giving me right predictions as you can see from the image.

Comment: My bad, didn't catch this. But anyway, maybe an issue in the source. Did you query the source data for the product 10? is it OK? the timestamp and the values?